# New Index on table cause table to be locked really often

Tags: sql-server, index, entity-framework, locking

Here are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trackers] (
    [IdTracker]             INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IMEI]                  NVARCHAR (16) NULL,
    [CreationDate]          DATETIME      NULL,
    [SuppressionDate]       DATETIME      NULL,
    [LastUpdateDate]        DATETIME      NULL,
    [BuyDate]               DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    [Status]                INT           NOT NULL,
    [LastTrackerUpdateDate] DATETIME      NULL,
    [IdLastTrackerPosition] INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdTracker] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrackerPositions] (
    [IdTrackerPosition] INT               IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TrackerId]         INT               NOT NULL,
    [Position]          [sys].[geography] NULL,
    [Date]              DATETIME          NOT NULL,
    [Speed]             REAL              NULL,
    [NbSatellites]      TINYINT           NULL,
    [Direction]         REAL              NULL,
    [HDOP]              REAL              NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdTrackerPosition] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [TrackerTrackerPosition] FOREIGN KEY ([TrackerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].     [Trackers] ([IdTracker])
 );
```

Tracker position is used to store positions send by car trackers. So I have a lot of insert going on.
And I often need to get the last position known for a tracker.

So here is a query generated by Entity Framework :

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[IdTrackerPosition] AS [IdTrackerPosition], 
    [Limit1].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
    [Limit1].[Position] AS [Position], 
    [Limit1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Limit1].[Speed] AS [Speed], 
    [Limit1].[NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
    [Limit1].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
    [Limit1].[HDOP] AS [HDOP]
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId]
        FROM [dbo].[TrackerPositions] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Position] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[TrackerId] IN (1, 48)) ) AS [Distinct1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project2].[IdTrackerPosition] AS [IdTrackerPosition], [Project2].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], [Project2].[Position] AS [Position], [Project2].[Date] AS [Date], [Project2].[Speed] AS [Speed], [Project2].[NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], [Project2].[Direction] AS [Direction], [Project2].[HDOP] AS [HDOP]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent2].[IdTrackerPosition] AS [IdTrackerPosition], 
            [Extent2].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
            [Extent2].[Position] AS [Position], 
            [Extent2].[Date] AS [Date], 
            [Extent2].[Speed] AS [Speed], 
            [Extent2].[NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
            [Extent2].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
            [Extent2].[HDOP] AS [HDOP]
            FROM [dbo].[TrackerPositions] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[Position] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[TrackerId] IN (1, 48)) AND ([Distinct1].[TrackerId] = [Extent2].[TrackerId])
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[IdTrackerPosition] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
```

And here an index suggested by SQL Server Studio :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_TrackerPositions_5_352108395__K2_3] ON [dbo].[TrackerPositions]
(
    [TrackerId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Position]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Performances are way better with the index, but most of my insert got locked...

Do you guys have any idea about a better index/select I could use ?

Edit :
The index you guyrs gave me was fine until then.
But I have some isues regarding performance now that my table is much bigger.

I tried this query, but the results are even worst :

```
    SELECT 
        [IdTrackerPosition] AS [IdTrackerPosition], 
        [TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
        [Position] AS [Position], 
        [Date] AS [Date], 
        [Speed] AS [Speed], 
        [NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
        [Direction] AS [Direction], 
        [HDOP] AS [HDOP]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        IdTrackerPosition,
        [TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
        [Position] AS [Position], 
        [Date] AS [Date], 
        [Speed] AS [Speed], 
        [NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
        [Direction] AS [Direction], 
        [HDOP] AS [HDOP],
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY TrackerId ORDER BY IdTrackerPosition DESC) AS rank_row
    FROM (
        SELECT
            IdTrackerPosition,
            [TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
            [Position] AS [Position], 
            [Date] AS [Date], 
            [Speed] AS [Speed], 
            [NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
            [Direction] AS [Direction], 
            [HDOP] AS [HDOP]
            FROM TrackerPositions tp
            WHERE tp.Position IS NOT null 
                AND [TrackerId] IN (9, 2, 24, 41, 10, 7, 1, 17, 16, 20, 3, 40, 13, 14, 18, 11, 12, 5, 6, 4, 8, 23, 19, 15, 42, 22, 39, 21, 33, 37, 38, 34, 26, 28, 36, 25, 29, 43, 27, 30, 35, 31, 32)               
        ) AS A
)  AS Z
WHERE rank_row <= 1
```

Thanks !

Comment: I'd say your problem is EF and the horrible queries it produces. I'd prefer an index on `(TrackerId, Position)` though (even without modifying the query) for this `TOP 1 .. ORDER BY Position DESC`

Comment: @PaulWhite thnx, I hadn't noticed that. And the order by is using `IdTrackerPosition`, not `Position`, so I was doubly sloppy in my comment. Your answer solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better index would be (assuming `ORDER BY IdTrackerPosition DESC` is correct, and the query should not specify `ORDER BY [Date] DESC` instead):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i -- Choose a better name!
ON dbo.TrackerPositions 
    (TrackerId, IdTrackerPosition DESC) 
INCLUDE 
    (Position, [Date], Speed, NbSatellites, Direction, HDOP);
```

The execution plan should look something like this:

[image: Execution plan]

If the `Position IS NOT NULL` predicate is frequent, or reasonably selective, you could add a computed column to the base table, and include that in the index - assuming the query can be expressed to reference the computed column rather than saying `Position IS NOT NULL` explicitly:

```
-- Computed column
ALTER TABLE dbo.TrackerPositions
ADD PositionIsNull 
AS 
    CASE 
        WHEN Position IS NULL THEN CONVERT(bit, 1) 
        ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0) 
    END;

-- Modified index
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i 
ON dbo.TrackerPositions 
    (TrackerId, PositionIsNull, IdTrackerPosition DESC) 
INCLUDE 
    (Position, [Date], Speed, NbSatellites, Direction, HDOP)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

Modified query:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[IdTrackerPosition] AS [IdTrackerPosition], 
    [Limit1].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
    [Limit1].[Position] AS [Position], 
    [Limit1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Limit1].[Speed] AS [Speed], 
    [Limit1].[NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
    [Limit1].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
    [Limit1].[HDOP] AS [HDOP]
    FROM   
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent1].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId]
            FROM [dbo].[TrackerPositions] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE 
                Extent1.PositionIsNull = CONVERT(bit, 0)
                AND ([Extent1].[TrackerId] IN (1, 48)) 
    ) AS [Distinct1]
    OUTER APPLY  
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Project2].[IdTrackerPosition] AS [IdTrackerPosition], 
        [Project2].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
        [Project2].[Position] AS [Position], 
        [Project2].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Project2].[Speed] AS [Speed], 
        [Project2].[NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
        [Project2].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
        [Project2].[HDOP] AS [HDOP]
        FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                [Extent2].[IdTrackerPosition] AS [IdTrackerPosition], 
                [Extent2].[TrackerId] AS [TrackerId], 
                [Extent2].[Position] AS [Position], 
                [Extent2].[Date] AS [Date], 
                [Extent2].[Speed] AS [Speed], 
                [Extent2].[NbSatellites] AS [NbSatellites], 
                [Extent2].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
                [Extent2].[HDOP] AS [HDOP]
            FROM [dbo].[TrackerPositions] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE 
                Extent2.PositionIsNull = CONVERT(bit, 0)
                AND ([Extent2].[TrackerId] IN (1, 48)) 
                AND ([Distinct1].[TrackerId] = [Extent2].[TrackerId])
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY 
            [Project2].[IdTrackerPosition] DESC 
    ) AS [Limit1]
```

Execution plan with computed column:

[image: Plan with computed column]

Comment: 98% of the time Position IS NOT NULL. I'll give your solution a try and I will le tyou know ! Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Your index should be on `(TrackerId ASC, [Date] DESC) INCLUDE (Position)` so that it can easily locate the most recent one for each Tracker.

But I really don't like the query from EF.

Edit:
...because "most recent" should mean "latest datetime", not "latest identity value"

Comment: Most recent is latest identity because trackers are configured to work like that ! Thanks !

Comment: So you could substitute `IdTrackerPosition` for `[Date]`